# How can i Insert the flow counter inside a regular expression?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to insert the flow counter 'i' inside an easy Reg Exp.
With this flow i want to verify if in a string of numbers appears only 1 type of number from 0 to 9.
At least 1 number must be different from the other inside the string

```
//Example:
var myString = "2222222222222222"; //Should Output Error
var myString2 = "2222222222222228"; //Should be OK

for(var i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    //I'm trying here to put the 'i' inside the regular expression
    var count = (myString.match(/[i]/g) || []).length;
    if(count == 16)
    {
       console.log("ERROR!");
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are matching `i` not the number in `i`. look into RegExp()

Comment: Of course i know this....that's why i want to put there the counter to check at every flow 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: Does this HAVE to be a regular expression? Given that you're already looping here, I think there are potentially better approaches to solving this. Let me know, and I can offer up something!

Comment: The counter means nothing when the regular expression is wrong to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aim is to match 16 digits and make sure they aren't all the same, you can do this with a single regex:

```js
//Example:
var myString = "2222222222222222"; //Should Output Error
var myString2 = "2222222222222228"; //Should be OK

var tester = /(\d)\1{15}/

function testString(str) {
    if (tester.test(str)) {
        console.log(str + " - ERROR!!!");
    } else {
        console.log(str + " - OK");
    }
}

testString(myString);
testString(myString2);
```

You match a digit in a group and then see if it's repeated another 15 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var regex = new RegExp(i, 'g');
var count = (myString.match(regex) || []).length;
```

Should be working properly

Answer (score 0):

use `new RegExp` to build your regular expression from a string.

For example to have `\d[1]\` `\d[2]\` etc...  you would do something like this (using template literals)

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    //I'm trying here to put the 'i' inside the regular expression
    var count = (myString.match(new RegExp(`\d{${i}}`, 'g') || []).length; // <-- here
    if(count == 16)
    {
       console.log("ERROR!");
       break;
    }
}
```

or string composition

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    //I'm trying here to put the 'i' inside the regular expression
    var count = (myString.match(new RegExp('\d{' + i + '}', 'g') || []).length; // <-- here
    if(count == 16)
    {
       console.log("ERROR!");
       break;
    }
}
```